# How to fetch previous values from a matching string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The idea is to delete everything from `record {` to the closing `}` of each `my_id_*` used as the variable.

I'm using this tool to test the expression: https://pythex.org/

We have the below file:

```
record {
    record {
        id my_id_1
        my_name_1
    }

    record {
        id my_id_2
        my_name_2
    }

    record {
        id my_id_3
        my_name_3
    }
}
```

And we want an output like:

Deleting my_id_3

```
record {
    record {
        id my_id_1
        my_name_1
    }

    record {
        id my_id_2
        my_name_2
    }
}
```

My actual regex does find the values from `my_id_*` to the first `}` but I'm not able to get the previous `record {`

Actual Regex:

```
(my_id_3.*?\})
```

I tried to index that in a second regex expression to get the correct `record {` entry but is not getting anything:

Second Try:

```
record \{(?!=/s.*)
```

Comment: You can prepend `record {\s+` to your record finding code. That will match `record { ` and any trailing white spaces. The full regex `record {\s+ my_id_3(\s+\w+\s+)+ }`, is working for me.

Comment: @Thymen I made a mistake, there is word set before the id that is breaking this regex. UPDATED THE SAMPLE FILE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this is working after updating the file content.

`(record \{[^\}\{]*my_id_1.*?\})`

`(record \{[^\}\{]*my_id_2.*?\})`

`(record \{[^\}\{]*my_id_3.*?\})`

Answer (score 0):

This works with the 'dotall' option set on https://pythex.org

`record \{[^\}\{]*(my_id_3.*?\})`

Comment: This one does not capture `record {` it gives same match output than `(my_id_3.*?\})` also I made a mistake, there is word set before the id that is breaking this regex. UPDATED THE SAMPLE FILE

Comment: looks like changing the capture moving the parentheses solved the issue on this one: `(record \{[^\}\{]*my_id_1.*?\})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` exluding matching `{` and `}` at the start and at the end of the pattern.

**Note** that you can omit the capturing group `()` around the pattern and that you don't have to escape the curly brackets inside the character class.

```
\brecord {[^{}]*my_id_1[^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1HsgoL/1)

If you want to remove all 3 parts at once, you can use a character class `[123]` listing all the numbers.

```
\brecord {[^{}]*my_id_[123][^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rc4vwv/1)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. space inside []

```
(\n[ ]*record {\n[ ]*my_id_3.*?\})
```

Comment: I made a mistake, there is word set before the id that is breaking this regex. UPDATED THE SAMPLE FILE

Comment: Please do not suggest using regex for parsing nested content.